# Ceph File system OS installation

Tags: installation, ceph

I'm building a Ceph cluster.

I've been reading for months and I can't find this information.

I am going to use Ubuntu 20.04

What is the file system that I have to use for the installation of the Ubuntu OS?

Only for the operating system, not for the OSDs

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think Ceph cares what filesystem you use for the host. Ceph manages its own filesystem on dedicated block devices, so it's not significantly impacted by your choice of  install filesystem.